# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.crypto.JceSecurity

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, jwt

We have spring mvc application in which we implemented JWT authentication. It is working fine in local environment but getting below error after deploying as a war file in linux server. Facing this issue for few API calls only some APIs are working fine with out any error.

I have checked policy jars already available

```
/jre/lib/security/policy/unlimited/US_export_policy.jar
/jre/lib/security/policy/unlimited/local_policy.jar
/jre/lib/security/policy/limited/US_export_policy.jar
/jre/lib/security/policy/limited/local_policy.jar


500 Internal Server Error: Root Cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.crypto.JceSecurity
    javax.crypto.Mac.getInstance(Mac.java:176)
    io.jsonwebtoken.impl.crypto.MacSigner.doGetMacInstance(MacSigner.java:64)
    io.jsonwebtoken.impl.crypto.MacSigner.getMacInstance(MacSigner.java:53)
    io.jsonwebtoken.impl.crypto.MacSigner.sign(MacSigner.java:47)
    io.jsonwebtoken.impl.crypto.MacValidator.isValid(MacValidator.java:33)
    io.jsonwebtoken.impl.crypto.DefaultJwtSignatureValidator.isValid(DefaultJwtSignatureValidator.java:61)
    io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:408)
    io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:541)
    io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(DefaultJwtParser.java:601)
    io.jsonwebtoken.impl.ImmutableJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(ImmutableJwtParser.java:173)
    com.gsshop.api.jwt.JWTManager.validateJwtToken(JWTManager.java:66)
```